# MySQL not showing foreign keys that are also primary keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Navicat does not show primary keys which are also foreign key on table report as foreign keys. Why?

I gave the image explaining the situation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key is a constraint that applies only to the referencing table. In your case, the `translate_talent_id` field has a foreign key constraint that references another field of another table.

On the other hand, `translator_id` is probably referenced by foreign keys in other tables. However, such foreign keys won't appear (or have any effect) on the the referenced table (`trl_translator` in this case). That is why your MySQL client is not showing any foreign keys on `translator_id`.

Comment: In here translator_id not only primary key but also foreign key referencing a primary key from a different table. Why i do this is inheritance. this table is subclass of another table

Comment: @kamil: Can you output the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE trl_translator`?